# Sending emails with attachments through the Mailgun API with PHP + cURL

Tags: php, curl, mailgun

I'm trying to send an email with 1-n attachment(s) through the Mailgun API using cURL. The below code successfully sends the email but no attachments are included.

Can anyone see why the below would not work?.. Any help would be very much appreciated.

```php
// Information submitted in form
$attachments = [];

if (!empty($_FILES['attachments']['tmp_name'][0]))
{
  $total = count($_FILES['attachments']['tmp_name']);
  // echo $total;
  for ($ct = 0; $ct < $total; $ct++)
  {
    $uploadfile = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), sha1($_FILES['attachments']['name'][$ct]));
    $filename = $_FILES['attachments']['name'][$ct];
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['attachments']['tmp_name'][$ct], $uploadfile)) {
      array_push($attachments, [ $uploadfile, $filename ]);
    } else {
      $msg .= 'Failed to move file to ' . $uploadfile;
    }
  }
}

// Build message body
$messageBody = "<p><strong>Attachments submitted!</strong></p>
                <p>All submitted documents are attached.</p>";

// Build email configuration
$config = array();
$config['api_key'] = $api_key;
$config['api_url'] = 'https://api.mailgun.net/v3/'.$api_domain.'/messages';

$message = array();
$message['from'] = $send_from;
$message['to'] = $send_to;
$message['subject'] = "Attachment submission";
$message['html'] = $messageBody;
$message['attachment'] = $attachments;

echo print_r($message);

// Run API call
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $config['api_url']);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "api:{$config['api_key']}");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 10);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $message);
$result = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
```

The `echo print_r($message);` prints the following:

```
Array ( [from] => xxx [to] => xxx [subject] => Attachment submission [html] =>
Attachments submitted!

All submitted documents are attached.

[attachment] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => /private/var/folders/qn/cwhh2swx3wj_qxbhzg3brcbh0000gn/T/78c3c8a74d56fdc1c74b21a1e5d15c49f2644d71AN8hnn [1] => test.jpg ) ) ) 1"{\n \"id\": \"<20180605063316.1.940D1781C7E44C03@xxx.com>\",\n \"message\": \"Queued. Thank you.\"\n}"
```